# Why when changing a button width it's changing the button position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
var w1 = 450;
var h1 = 150;
Rect rect1 = new Rect((Screen.width-w1)/2, (Screen.height-h1)/2 + 100, w1, h1);

if (GUI.Button (new Rect (rect1.x, rect1.y, 150, 20), "GENERATE RANDOM NUMBERS")) {

            }
```

When it was w1 and h1 both 150 it was in the middle of the screen + 100 on the height but the text inside the button was not shown completly. So i wanted to change the button width. So i changed the w1 from 150 to 350 then to 450 but it didn't change the button width just moved the button.

Comment: You shouldn't be using this for a Button. You need to use the [Button](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button) component from new UI system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about Unity3D but it seems in this line:

```
Rect rect1 = new Rect((Screen.width-w1)/2, (Screen.height-h1)/2 + 100, w1, h1);
```

that you use `w1` for the value of the x-position. That would mean by changing this value you would shift the rectangle.